# Android activity getting halt during loop with inflator

Tags: android, android-activity, layout-inflater

My code is working absolutely fine. But the problem is that after I receive the Data from the web service. When I start the Loop for create multiple row's then My Activity get halted for 5 to 10 seconds. The maximum record that can be received from service is not more than 100.

How I can solve this issue? Without halting my activity It should generate multiple records. Because I have already a few records for iteration.

```
LinearLayout parentLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.sheet);
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
View view;
JSONArray receivedData = (JSONArray) json.get("RESPONSE_DATA");
for(int i=0; i<receivedData.length(); i++){
    view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parentLayout, false);
    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title1)).setText( (((JSONObject)receivedData.getJSONObject(i)).get("title1")).toString() );
    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title2)).setText( (((JSONObject)receivedData.getJSONObject(i)).get("title2")).toString() );
    ToggleButton button = (ToggleButton)view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            View parentView = (View)buttonView.getParent();
            if(isChecked){
                parentView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
            }else{
                parentView.setBackgroundColor(0xffDF9292);
            }
        }
    });
    parentLayout.addView(view);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have here is a great place to use an adapter. 
See [this link](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) at Android Developers for more details.

You activity probably gets halted because you do too much work on the UI thread. I would also imagine that it gets laggy due to way too many UI objects being alive at the moment. All that will get fixed when you use a list with an adapter.

[**edit**]

I think that [this tutorial from Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) might be a better place to start.

Comment: Thanks @MatBos 
Seconds link is more usefull

Answer (score 0):

The activity halts because you are running your code on the main activity thread. I suggest you to use something of asynchronous, try to implement your code inside an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) (but append the view in onPostExecute).
Another way is to add a ListView and load your data with a custom ArrayAdapter, [this is an example](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#listview_listviewexample) .

I hope i have helped you